# Show hidden div permanently throughout website after clicking on a <a> href link once

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Show hidden div permanently throw out website after clicking on a  href link once**

*An example how this should work:*
The (little-header) div is hidden in the start, but when clicking once on the parent page e.g.(page 1) the (little-header) gets visible throughout the website even though you enter a new page or refresh the site.

```
 <div class="big-header">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="little-header">
   <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sub Page 1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sub Page 1.2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sub Page 3.3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/179/

I can imagine this being done by Jquery.
Anything would be a big help. Cheers!

Comment: Set a cookie or use localStorage to tell which DIVs should be shown. When the page reloads, check the cookie and show those DIVs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store a flag if the menu has been shown, then use a script like this to only execute the show function once.

In response to your comment below, I've added logic so that if this script is included on multiple pages then it will work independently for each page. I do this by using [`Window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to store the information separately for each page visited.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/182/))

```
var hide = localStorage[location] ? false : true;
var hidden = document.querySelector('.little-header');
if(hide) {
    hidden.style.display = 'none';
    document.onclick = function() {
        localStorage[location] = true;
        hidden.style.display = '';
        document.onclick = '';
        console.log('click');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tiny Giant this works great, now how would I make it RESET this function when goning to another page e.g. mywebsite.com/anotherpage/? anytinhg that comes after /? will not get RESET????  localStorage.clear(); somthing??

Comment: @user3603497 I've updated the code above. The way this will function is that it will store the flag for each page. This doesn't "reset" per se, so when you visit a new page on your website it will seem like it resets, but when you navigate back to a page that you've already "clicked" then it will still be open. If this is not the functionality you're looking for then I can make it work the other way.

Answer (score 3):

As @Barmar and @Tiny Giant have said, localStorage works well and is very easy to use. Here's a jQuery version.

```
$(function () {
    var showLittleHeader = localStorage.getItem('show_little_header');
    if (showLittleHeader) {
        $('.little-header').show();
    }
    $('.big-header').on('click', 'a', function () {
        localStorage.setItem('show_little_header', 1);
        $('.little-header').show();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wqpjfvy7/